# Use obtain in tactic mode in Lean theorem prover

Tags: lean

How do I use a hypothesis of the shape

```
H : exists x, P x
```

in tactic mode? In term mode I would use

```
obtain x Hx, from H,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same syntax:

```
example (A : Type) (p : A × A) : A :=
begin
  obtain x y, from p, x
end
```

You can of course re-enter tactic mode by using `begin...end` after `from`.

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea why this was not working yesterday.

Comment: now I do know: this does not work for a Prop statement 
`Hex : exists x, P x` .
You need to do
`cases Hex with x Px,`